# Do we need to install Chrome binaries on Selenium grid to avoid getting "WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have set up a new selenium grid on Linux server executing the following way

The first command --> 'java -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub'

Second --> 'java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./grid/chromedriver -jar ./selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.39.73:4444/grid/register/'

After going through the previous posts, helpers have been suggested to specify the driver path as I did. But still getting the same below error. Do I have to install the Chrome binary in the default location(/usr/bin/google-chrome) even if I want to use selenium grid?

````
[chrome #01-1] C:\Users\User1\Projects\ui-auto.qa\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546
[chrome #01-1]         throw new ctor(message);
[chrome #01-1]               ^
[chrome #01-1] WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
[chrome #01-1]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
[chrome #01-1] Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
[chrome #01-1] Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
[chrome #01-1] System info: host: 'ip-10-0-39-73', ip: '10.0.39.73', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.77-70.59.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
[chrome #01-1] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[chrome #01-1]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\User1\Projects\ui-auto.qa\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
[chrome #01-1]     at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\User1\Projects\ui-auto.qa\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
[chrome #01-1]     at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\User1\Projects\ui-auto.qa\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
[chrome #01-1]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)```
````

Comment: Yes you need chrome installed in the hub.

Comment: Rather raising this question you should have asked this query in your previous question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this is a different question because I want specifically want to know whether we have to install browser binaries separately to the driver. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i Think server not access the  chrome binary from your user directory you can bcz chrome installed on local machine

you can simply instruct Chromedriver where to look for Chrome Binary that might help

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions= new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setBinary("C:\\please make sure path is correct till parent filder \\Chrome.exe");

ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```